# Why does tracking different plant states result in totally different observer estimates?

Tags: sensor, control, matlab, simulink

I am trying to design a [Luenberger observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer) (or a full state feedback observer) such that with one sensor available I can estimate all the states. A good tutorial is shown [here](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlStateSpace#23).

My system is 4th order:

```
num = [-0.00198 2];
den = [1 0.1201 12.22 0.4201 2];
sys = tf(num,den);
[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(num,den);
```

First I have a row vector of poles to get my desired response:

```
poles = [-2.6 + 1i*2.39, -2.6 - 1i*2.39, -100, -120];
K = acker(A,B,poles)
rank(obsv(A,C));  % =4
Mo = rank([C;C*A;C*A^2;C*A^3]) % =4
```

I then proceed to calculate the plant poles and thus the poles I want for my observer should be around 3x faster.

```
plant = (A-B*K);
poles_cl = eig(plant)

poles = 3*poles_cl  % THIS IS WRONG
des_poles = (min(real(poles_cl))*3)-(1:4); %This is better

des_poles =

 -361.0000 -362.0000 -363.0000 -364.0000
```

I then proceed to use Ackermann's formula for pole placement using the new poles:

```
% design observer by placing poles of A-LC at des_poles 
L=acker(A',C',poles_des)'
eig_obs = eig(A-L*C) 

L =

   1.0e+09 *

    8.6121
    0.1037
    0.0005
    0.0000

eig_obs =

 -361.0000
 -362.0000
 -363.0000
 -364.0000
```

And finally plot. For the observer (software) to give us all the states as output we need to set `C = eye(4)`:

```
C = eye(4);
mysys=ss(A-L*C,[B L],C,0); %Not sure if this is correct
tf(mysys)
step(mysys)
```

Four outputs can be seen:

[image]

Following this model for a full state feedback observer:

[image]

I am then trying to verify the results on Simulink and am having issue with the block diagram. As can be  seen I have two state space models, one for the real plant and one for the observer.

In the below diagram I am comparing state 1, which results in the second graph depicted below.

[image]

I am using the base workspace generated by the code above:

[image]

Upon running I get an output from the observer which does not track or follow the plant as expected:

**Actual and Observer states when comparing state 4 through summing block:**

[image]

**Actual and Observer states when comparing state 1 through summing block:**

[image]

Any suggestions on why the state I choose to compare via the summing block is effecting the observer estimations would be appreciated.

---

Observer Parameters:

[image]

Plant Parameters:

[image]

1. **Why does the state which I am comparing, effect the observer response?**

Comment: First -- I thought a Luenberger observer is reduced-state.  Doesn't that mean a 3-state observer?

Comment: Second -- did you look at the resulting system matrices and vectors, to make sure the values looked reasonable?

Comment: Third -- you may want to put together the augmented system (plant model + observer), check it visually to see if it looks reasonable, and then to simulate it (I assume you use step, but I'm a Scilab guy not a Matlab guy).

Comment: @TimWescott, yes resulting eigenvalues and matrices for `eig(A-B*K)` and `eig(A-L*C)`, were checked and all seemed to be reasonable.

Comment: @TimWescott, using a Luenberger observer I should be able to estimate all states from a single state. The Luenberger observer is a minimum order observer such that it is designed to reconstruct all state variables.

Comment: You can construct an observer with as many fewer states as there are linearly independent rows in the output gain matrix (*C* in your notation).  So a 4-state SISO system could have a 3-state observer (and a 4-state system with four outputs could conceivably have a zero-state observer).  It's been a while since I've gone around dotting academic 'i's and 't's, so I forgot the nomenclature.

Comment: As I just noted in the edited question, the only observer state which is following the actual plant state, is the state compared directly in the summing block. Thus the observer is actually working for a single state out of the four, which is pretty useless. I want to be able to determine _all states_ from one single plant state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer pertains to the question title "How to design an observer to estimate all states from a single sensor".

I'm pretty sure that you have the input vector to the compensator reversed.  You either need to reverse the order that signals go into the multiplexer, or you need to reverse the order of the B matrix in the compensator (by changing it to [L B].  For reference here's a picture.

By picking off the \$x_1\$ term from your state vector you are also effectively using \$C=\left[\matrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0}\right]\$.  See the picture.  I suspect, but do not know, that the `tf2ss` function returns `C=[0 0 0 1]`, you should check this.

[image]

Note that Simulink will let you draw out the compensator pretty much the way it's done here -- it'll accept matrix gains and carry vector signals, and IIRC integrate vectors.  So you can have a complete block diagram of what you want, instead of trying to get all the graphical 'i's and 't's dotted to match the textual specification in the definition block.

[image: Figure 4.2-1 from *Linear Systems*]

From *Linear Systems*, Kailath, Prentice-Hall, 1980.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed the order of the B matrix and unexpectedly Simulink is now taking approximately 10 minutes to get to 1% completion.  According to this [link](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/~wedeward/EE544/FA05/example8.html) it should be [B L].

Comment: According to that link, the plant input is going into the top of the multiplexer, and the observer feedback is going to the bottom.  You have that order reversed in your diagram.

Comment: For a test, try setting your k values to zero and see if your observer follows your plant.  That'll at least tell you if the observer is working correctly.

Comment: Yes, setting the K to zero gives good approximations, even though the gain is still off.

Comment: This gives a much better output. I am noticing that the state I choose to compare via the summing block makes a big difference to the estimated states. For example, comparing state 4 results in good estimations of all states but comparing state 1 only results in good estimation of state 1

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "even though the gain is still off".  You should also note that the block diagram you drew assumes that B = [1; 0; 0; 0].  If that's not what gets generated by tf2ss, then your whole set of computations will be wrong.

Comment: You may ignore that statement, since I had not yet tested thoroughly enough. I updated question with graphs after your suggestion. Yes that is what is generated by tf2ss. It is directly imported from matlab workspace.

Comment: I'm sorry.  The block diagram you drew assumes that the **C** matrix from tf2ss is C = [1 0 0 0].  I suspect it actually equals [0 0 0 1], particularly if B = [1; 0; 0; 0].  If that's the case, then the reason that comparing state 4 works so much better is because that's actually what the observer is designed for.

Comment: Matrix C is an eye matrix from what I can tell. Diagonal 1's give all states as ouput

Comment: @TimWescott, I don't quite understand why the block diagram assumes matrix C is [1 0 0 0]. Matrix C = eye(4) meaning it has 4 rows and four columns with the main diagonal containing 1's.

Comment: Answer edited.  I really do understand that C = eye(4) means that you're *telling Simulink* that C is the identity matrix.  But picking off \$x_1\$ to use for feedback means that you are **effectively** setting C = [1 0 0 0].

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I had misinterpreted your previous comment.

Comment: @TimWescott, apologies for my incompetence but finally I am understanding your comments better. My `tf2ss` returns `C = [0 0 0 2];` And that is why state 4 is the only state I can use to observe the plant. I am trying to understand, do I need to divide by 2 to get to an equivalent `C = [0 0 0 1];` matrix?

Comment: You should pick off \$x_4\$ and *multiply* by two before the summing junction.  Then your effective value of C will be equal to the design value.

Answer (score 1):

This answer pertains to the current title ("Why Does Tracking Different Plant States Result In Totally Different Observer Estimates").

The answer is -- turn off Matlab until you know what you're doing, and then *do the math*.  The answer should be clear.  If it's not, do the math some more.

The observer equations (from the picture in my first answer) are $$ 
\frac{d\hat{x}}{dt} = A \hat{x} + B u + L\left(y - \hat{y}\right), \hat{y} = C \hat{x}$$

Using simple linear algebra, you can eliminate the reference to \$\hat{y}\$ in the first equation:$$ 
\frac{d\hat{x}}{dt} = \left(A - LC\right) \hat{x} + 
\left[\matrix{B & L}\right] \left[\matrix{u \\ y}\right], \hat{y} = C \hat{x}$$

The phrase "Tracking different plant states" translates, mathematically, to "changing the value of \$C\$".  Looking at the second equation above, it's pretty obvious that if \$A - LC_1 \ne A - LC_2\$, then the two systems are going to act differently.  It's really that simple.

Comment: Thanks for the above explanation. The math makes more sense now, however even though it may seem simple to you, I am not fully understanding how this can be solved. While I get that `A-LC1` is not equal to `A-LC2`,  I still need a way to be able to track all plant states from any single plant state.. I would have thought that from any state (or any value of C) the observer would be able to track the other states accordingly. As I present in the question (and as you show above) this is certainly not the case.

Comment: I may be going off in a tangent or not replying directly to your answer but, the plant states should be estimated irrespective of which state I choose to track.

Comment: In a word, no.  Just to save space, assume a 2nd-order system with \$A=\left[\matrix{-3 & 0 \\ 1 & -3}\right]\$, \$B=\left[\matrix{1 \\ 0}\right]\$ and \$C=\left[\matrix{0 & 1}\right]\$.  That's an observable system, because \$x_1\$ is directly affected by the input, and \$x_2\$ is directly affected by \$x_1\$.  Now change \$C\$ to \$C=\left[\matrix{1 & 0}\right]\$.  Intuitively, the system is no longer observable because \$x_1\$ is unaffected by \$x_2\$.

Comment: Mathematically, the system is no longer observable because the observability check matrix is singular: \$O=\left[\matrix{1 & 0 \\ -3 & 0}\right]\$.

Comment: [This set of lecture notes](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~gajic/psfiles/chap5traCO.pdf) (pulled randomly from the Internet -- it makes sense but I make no guarantees) explains checking for observability.  If it's entirely new to you I suggest you get a good book on state space control and study up.  If it reminds you of something you've been taught, I suggest you pull out your old book and notes and study up.